# includes invalid characters for a local volume name,. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path

Tags: docker, docker-run

I ran docker run -v and it shows error as invalid characters in local volume name.

```
"If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path"
```

also is printed in the terminal.

Tried replacing `-v` with `--mount` but gives error on parameters

```
sudo docker build -t="sreedath/tensorflow_1.1.0_py3" .

sudo docker run -p 8888:8888 --name=tensorflow_sreedath_py3 -v home/sreedath/Mytest/LSTM-Sentiment-Analysis:/LSTM-Sentiment-Analysis -it sreedath/tensorflow_1.1.0_py3
```

desired output is to get the localhost at `port:8888`, but due to error the local host is not working

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear :

> If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.

You should use **absolute** path for host directories, otherwise `docker` consider them as volumes. Here, `home/sreedath/Mytest/LSTM-Sentiment-Analysis` is considered as a volume, and it contains invalid characters, that's why you get the error.

To mount a host directory (assuming `/home/sreedath/Mytest/LSTM-Sentiment-Analysis` exists on your host), you should use :

```
sudo docker run \
    -p 8888:8888 \
    --name=tensorflow_sreedath_py3 \
    -v /home/sreedath/Mytest/LSTM-Sentiment-Analysis:/LSTM-Sentiment-Analysis \
    -it sreedath/tensorflow_1.1.0_py3
```

Notice the `/` at the beginning of `/home/sreedath/Mytest/LSTM-Sentiment-Analysis` (absolute path).